# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/xxx/xxx/viewmodels/CameraXViewModel;

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, android-camerax

The APK is generated and everything works at compile time but app crash at runtime. The crash is when launching the camera module for barcode scanning implemented with CameraX.

Here is the crash log:

```
08-22 17:31:16.537 16660-16660/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 16660
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/xxx/xxx/viewmodels/CameraXViewModel;
        at com.xxx.xxx.barcode.CameraXLivePreviewActivity.onCreate(CameraXLivePreviewActivity.kt:94)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7314)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7305)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2948)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3073)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1774)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7055)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:523)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:836)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.xxx.viewmodels.CameraXViewModel" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.xxx-LKiFwx0pU2KUfueyYsAm-w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxx.xxx-LKiFwx0pU2KUfueyYsAm-w==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.xxx.xxx-LKiFwx0pU2KUfueyYsAm-w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
```

Here is line 94 where the ViewModel is accessed.

[image]

Kindly refer my build details.

Here is the project-level **build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}


android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.2.13"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            buildConfigField "String", "AREA", "\"\""
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            buildConfigField "String", "AREA", "\"\""
        }
        ABC {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            buildConfigField "String", "AREA", "\"_A\""

        }
        XYZ {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            buildConfigField "String", "AREA", "\"_X\""
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "appVariant", "projectCode"
    productFlavors {
        A {
            dimension "appVariant"
        }
        B {
            dimension "appVariant"
        }
        C {
            dimension "appVariant"
        }
        D {
            dimension "appVariant"
        }
        DEV {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
        QA {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
        LIVE {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
        DEMO {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
        BETA {
            dimension "projectCode"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def project = "TEST_PROJECT"
            def SEP = "_"
            def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
            def projcode = variant.productFlavors[1].name
            def buildType = variant.buildType.name
            def buildTypeName = "";
            switch (buildType) {
                case "ABC": buildTypeName = SEP + "AB"; break;
                case "XYZ": buildTypeName = SEP + "XY"; break;
                default:
                    buildTypeName = "";
            }

            def version = variant.versionName
            def date = new Date();
            def formattedDate = date.format('ddMMyy_HHmm')

            def newApkName = project + buildTypeName + SEP + flavor + SEP + projcode + SEP + version + ".apk"

            outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:7.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:22.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Retrofit and GSON
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'

    //Kotlin Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"


    //Kodein Dependency Injection
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:6.2.1"
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:6.2.1"

    //Android Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"
    kapt  "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

    //Android Navigation Architecture
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.0-alpha02"

    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-databinding:2.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.0"

    //Image loading
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828"

    //barcode
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.0.0'

    // CameraX
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    // On Device Machine Learnings
    implementation "com.google.android.odml:image:1.0.0-beta1"
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:camera:16.0.0-beta1'

    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'

    implementation(files("./libs/scandecode-release.aar"))
    implementation 'com.valdesekamdem.library:md-toast:0.9.0'
    implementation 'com.tt:whorlviewlibrary:1.0.3'
}
```

**Not sure what is wrong**.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe proguard has been doing too much renaming. Try turning proguard off to check whether this is the cause.

Comment: @Thomas I have tried it, but not working.

Comment: try to create viewModel with kt extention like this val viewModel by viewModels<YourViewMode>()

Comment: @Hamza no luck.

Comment: please share viewmdoel class also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solved!.***

Implemented multidex from the developer site.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Also there were two view model classes CameraXViewModel & CameraXviewModel.kt, removed the file CameraXviewModel.kt from the project. CameraXViewModel is the one which is used and CameraXviewModel was not referenced any where in the project.

ASFAIK Java and Kotlin is case sensitive for classes, so ideally it should work. Here everything compiled and APK generated but app crashed at runtime.
Hope this helps someone.